# In to how many ways we can call or execute one package from other package in ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, msbi

In recent interviews i have come across with this question that what are the ways from which you can or execute one package from other package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using SSIS 2012+ in SSIS Catalog - Project mode.

1. Call another package from this project in Package task
2. Start package with stored procedures in SSISDB - in SQL Tasks
3. Create SQL Job to execute package, then start this Job from SQL Task
4. Create Execute cmd task, which start package with dtexec
5. Create Script task which starts package

Approaches 2-5 basically are doing the same - start out of process execution of some package, with either calling SSISDB SPs or DLL directly, or with dtexec wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the approaches AFAIK.

1. Using Execute Process Task.
2. Using SQL Agent and call the agent in SSIS package.
3. Using command line (dtexec).
4. Using Scripting (.net script to execute dtsx file).
5. Using Stored Procedure.
6. Using a Batch file and calling batch file a package.

Answer (score 0):

ExecutePackageTask, StoredProcedure(sql),dtexec.exe utitlity and dtexecui.exe